# JQuery/JavaScript - Increment parent rowspan by 1 and put first child cells underneath on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to make column one (assigned class) have its rowspan incremented by one on click. Also I am wanting basically all the contents under column two (which also has its own class) to basically go underneath column one when I click column one. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/oyp4rkbp/12/) if anyone has any advice I would be appreciative! Basically kind of like excel pivot table functionality if anyone is familiar with that.

```
$(function dotIt() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    var rowspan0 = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    $(this).attr('rowspan', rowspan0 + 1);
    // $(this).attr('rowspan').size() + 1;
  });
});
```

basically after you click the parent, I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: If you can you share an image of the table before and after click, I think that would help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, except that the jquery document ready function is incorrect. It should be `$(function(){ .... })` instead of `$(funciton doIt(){ .... });`. You need to convert the rowspan0 to int as the `$(this).attr('rowspan')` will return as string. You may refer to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85068fpn/)

Comment: yeah i fixed that but its not working, still have something wrong

Comment: really close but not quite what i was looking for...please see my picture above

Comment: to add what I believe i need to happen is hide the header for child0 on click and move its contents under the parent

Comment: Yes, you would need to manipulate the columns by using jquery insertAfter or append.

Comment: I made some modifications on the fiddle, its just a trial but it might get you started on what you want regarding the movement of the child column to the parent column.

Comment: Sorry for that. Please access the fiddle again

Comment: the jsfiddle i see no change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114297/discussion-between-bon-macalindong-and-khemikal).